# How to assign graph-node label as node value?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I am facing the following problem: I need to work on several already-designed graphs, accessible in ".DOT" format. Mathematica can perfectly read these graphs, however because the nodes of the graphs only contains "IDs" instead of the actual textual data I'm interrested in. The data are stored in node-labels.

So if I do a something like that:

```
argGraph = Import["http://www.arg.dundee.ac.uk/AIFdb/dot/4"]
VertexList[argGraph]
```

I only get a list of IDs:
    {"234", "235", "236", "237", "238", "239"}

How can I easily reformat the graph so that the labels are assigned as node values ?

The Graph looks like this:

[image]

and is a representation of this argument map: [Argument Map](http://www.arg.dundee.ac.uk/AIFdb/argview/4)
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: Two methods to get the vertex labels of a `Graph` object:**

1. **`PropertyValue`**: `PropertyValue[{grph, #}, VertexLabels] & /@ VertexList[grph]`
2. **`Options`**:  `VertexLabels /. Options[grph]` gives the rules mapping vertex names to vertex labels.

Example:

```
  argGraph = Import["http://www.arg.dundee.ac.uk/AIFdb/dot/4"];

  PropertyValue[{argGraph, #}, VertexLabels] & /@ VertexList[argGraph]
  (* {"The object is red.", "The object looks red.", 
     "Things which look red are normally red.", 
      "The object is illuminated by a red light.", 
      "RA", "CA"} *)
  VertexLabels /. Options[argGraph]
  (* {"239" -> "CA", "237" -> "The object is illuminated by a red light.", 
     "236" -> "Things which look red are normally red.", 
     "235" -> "The object looks red.", "234" -> "The object is red.", 
     "238" -> "RA"} *)
```

**Using `Graph`**

```
 Graph[EdgeList[argGraph],
 VertexLabels -> (MapAt[Placed[Framed[Style[#], FrameStyle -> None, 
     Background -> Directive[Opacity[.8], LightBlue]],
    {1/2, 1/2}] &, #, {2}] & /@ (VertexLabels /. Options[argGraph])),
 VertexStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[None], White], 
 GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding",
 ImagePadding -> 80, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**Using `GraphPlot`**

```
  GraphPlot[EdgeList[argGraph] /. (VertexLabels /. Options[argGraph]) /. 
  DirectedEdge -> Rule,   VertexLabeling -> True,
  VertexRenderingFunction -> (Text[#2, #1, Background -> LightBlue] &),
  ImageSize -> 500, Method -> "SpringEmbedding", DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:** Constructing new graphs by replacing vertices with vertex labels:

```
 rplcmntRule =   VertexLabels /. Options[argGraph]

 newVertices = VertexList[argGraph] /. rplcmntRule;
 newEdges = EdgeList[argGraph] /. rplcmntRule
 (* {"RA" \[DirectedEdge] "The object is red.", 
  "The object looks red." \[DirectedEdge] "RA", 
  "Things which look red are normally red." \[DirectedEdge] "RA", 
  "CA" \[DirectedEdge] "RA", 
  "The object is illuminated by a red light." \[DirectedEdge] "CA"} *)

 Graph[newEdges, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {1/2, 1/2}], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "RoundedRectangle", 
 VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .1}]
```

[image]

A more "readable" version:

```
 Graph[newEdges, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {1/2, 1/2}],
 VertexStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[None], White], 
 VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .1},
 ImagePadding -> 70, GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks so much!

Comment: @afentis, my pleasure.

Comment: Just a minor issue, if I try with a more complex graph such as the one found at "http://www.arg.dundee.ac.uk/AIFdb/dot/3", I get a 
    Graph::supp: Mixed graphs and multigraphs are not supported.
If you have any idea why this error occurs it would be appreciated :) otherwise, it's not a major issue...

Comment: @afentis, `Graph` does not support mixed graphs (that have both directed and undirected edges) and multigraphs (multiple edges between two nodes). This may be a good reason to reconsider your approach; because in any reasonable argGraph you will have multiple nodes with `RA` and `CA` labels, when multiple `RA` or `CA`  nodes are "collapsed" in a single node, we end up with a multigraph.

Comment: You are completely right, I had not considered this issue. I was under the impression that Mathematica could support multigraphs. I will try to find a way to overcome this issue.

Comment: afentis, You can use `GraphPlot` instead of `Graph`. But ... it seems to me the most important part of the argGraph logic is the construction of `RA` and `CA` nodes and they must have distinct identities as "links" between "args". Compare, for example, `GraphPlot[EdgeList[argGraph2] /. DirectedEdge -> Rule, VertexLabeling -> True, ImageSize -> Large]` versus `GraphPlot[EdgeList[argGraph2] /. rplcmntRule2 /. DirectedEdge -> Rule, VertexLabeling -> True, ImageSize -> Large]`. So, I think it is better to keep labels as labels. Perhaps, a work-around could be ...

Comment: ... to re-label the `RA` and `CA` nodes as `RA-1`,`RA-2` ... `CA-1`, `CA-2` ... etc to preserve their identities.

Comment: Once again, you are totally right, the most important element for me is the "data modelling" not (yet) the visualisation part, and for that the "links" are critical. The "ideal" scenario would be to just leave the labels "RA"/"CA" as labels and the rest as real data-nodes.
Your work-around suggestion is definitely worth trying as well :) !

Comment: Note that as of version 12.1 PropertyValue [has been superseded](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PropertyValue.html) by [AnnotationValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnnotationValue.html).